# Is it fine to add a sending domain which is already in use by other platform in Pardot?

Tags: pardot, deliverability

We want to add a sending domain in Pardot

This sending domain is already used by our client in an other platform

I don't know if this will create a problem for us ? Or is it going to be completly fine ?

Comment: Yes but you have to be careful: https://serverfault.com/questions/1015237/how-does-dkim-work-when-sending-emails-from-multiple-sources-servers

Answer (score 1):

In Pardot if you want to do this, you will need to work with Pardot Support to make sure everything is right on their end. I've seen it done in a couple of different Pardot orgs.